# Looping inside a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How does a loop work in a string like this?

```
var w = window.open('','','width=792,height=612');
$(w.document.body).html('<div>'+  
    '<ul>' + 
    for(var i=o; i<=10; i++){
        '<li>'+ i +'</li>'+
    }
    '</ul>'+
    '</div>');
```

Comment: Hi Marshall, please expand the question a little and correct grammar.
Also explain what you expect to happen and give some context if you want better answers.

Comment: A `for` loop does not return anything so attempting to "add it" somewhere makes no sense.  Build the string in advance then assign it.

Comment: you can create an dynamic table by user input rows and columns !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly suggest you create your string before inserting it into your table.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var w = window.open('','','width=792,height=612');
  var myString = "";
   for(var i=0; i<=10; i++){
     myString += "<tr><td>hello</td></tr>";
  }
  $('body').html('<table>' + myString + '</table>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

</body>
```

I also corrected a lot of your code since there was a few error, ex: var i = o instead of i = 0.